# VBA Only step through works

Tags: excel, vba

everyone.

I have a very simple macro that works when i step through but doesn't work when I run the subroutine. I've looked through other posts but couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

My macro is intended to open a master file and delete the unneeded sheets. I want to use this macro to easily set up a workbook for an analysis that already has all the tags I need. When i run the macro it opens the correct file but doesn't delete any sheets. If it matters, I'm running this as a personal macro with a keyboard shortcut.

Here is the macro:

```
Sub Tags_Drop()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\canada.compassgroup.corp\to\Finance\Chartwells\Chartwells F20\Chartwells Master Tracker.xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PnL Tags Build Data Dump").Delete

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("F21 Calendar").Delete

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("F20 Calendar").Delete

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("F19 Calendar").Delete

Workbooks("Chartwells Master Tracker.xlsx").SaveAs ("New Book.xlsx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps `ActiveWorkbook` isn't the workbook you think it is and/or isn't the workbook that you are saving. It is better to use fully qualified workbook variables.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on `ActiveWorkbook`. `Workbooks.Open` returns a workbook object that you should reference.

```
Sub Tags_Drop()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\canada.compassgroup.corp\to\Finance\Chartwells\Chartwells F20\Chartwells Master Tracker.xlsx")

    wb.Sheets("PnL Tags Build Data Dump").Delete
    wb.Sheets("F21 Calendar").Delete    

    ' and so on

    wb.SaveAs "New Book.xlsx"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: And you could also use a `With` block to hold the workbook reference; e.g `With Workbooks.Open(...)` `.Sheets(...).Delete` ... `End With`

Comment: Another option, yes.

Comment: Hey, BigBen. Thanks for responding so quickly.

I used the code you provided and the same problem persists: it works when i step through but not when i run the macro. My apologies for being such a vba noob.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code?

Comment: No I dont. I changed the code to:

Sub Tags_Drop()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\canada.compassgroup.corp\to\Finance\Chartwells\Chartwells F20\Chartwells Master Tracker.xlsx")

wb.Sheets("PnL Tags Build Data Dump").Delete

wb.Sheets("F21 Calendar").Delete

wb.Sheets("F20 Calendar").Delete

wb.Sheets("F19 Calendar").Delete

wb.SaveAs ("New Book.xlsx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Comment: Now when i step through it stops at the Workbooks.open line but still deletes the proper sheets. However when i run instead of step through it fails. Thanks again for taking the time to help.